# How can I use or share the integrated webcam on my laptop as a webcam on my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I have a Mac Book Pro with a built in webcam, very useful for gmail chat, skype, etc.  Often times I have it sitting on a large desk, with a desktop machine that has two monitors.

Both laptop and desktop are running Windows 7 64bit Professional.

I would like to be able to use the webcam on my desktop as if it was attached directly to the computer itself.  Then a video chat with someone would allow me to use a program from the desktop, view incoming video on the desktop, with the only trade off is the person I'm communicating with would have an off center view.

I'm looking for some sort of lead on a method of sharing a USB device via software perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the following software solutions, all of them commercial, none of which I have tested, and variability in what OS is supported.

http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/
http://www.incentivespro.com/usb-redirector.html
http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html
http://www.intellidriver.com/products_1.16.html

Can anyone find a free or open source solution?