# Share MacBook webcam with PC over Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, macbook, remote-access, webcam

I have a desktop PC in an office with a webcam attached. Normally when  I'm **in the office** I use this for meetings, etc.

I would like to connect to this PC remotely via RDP, but from my MacBook. One thing I need to be able to do is join meetings *through* RDP, sharing the mic and webcam **of my MacBook** to the PC.

Is this possible, either via Microsoft Remote Desktop, or other third-party tools?

This seems similar to this ~7-year old question, but I was hoping to re-open it for more current discussion:

[How can I use or share the integrated webcam on my laptop as a webcam on my desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/197725/how-can-i-use-or-share-the-integrated-webcam-on-my-laptop-as-a-webcam-on-my-desk)

The software in the above answer is either EOL (dead links) or ~$100. I'd like to find a way to do this via Apple Remote Desktop, Remote Desktop Connection, or some other free/open-source/more reasonably-priced (and less sketchy looking) tool.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an iPad you can try [iCam](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icam-webcam-video-streaming/id296273730?mt=8)
"iCam allows you to remotely monitor multiple live video and audio webcam feeds"

Comment: Huh, say what, come again???

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I'll throw my hat in for what it's worth:

<s>Teamviewer has a built-in video feature either in its meeting settings and/or in its remote control session settings. I suggest looking into this, however, I also strongly recommend that **IF** you use this software, you either set the default session password length to the highest setting or completely disable it as I have. Once you've associated the remote PC to your Teamviewer account, you can access it from any other device you're logged into, including mobile devices, such as an iPhone or iPad.</s>

[NoMachine](https://nomachine.com/) offers hardware passthrough of devices, such as a microphone or camera.

Hope my input was helpful!

Comment: I'm looking specifically to pass my local webcam through over a piece of Remote Desktop software, I don't think TeamViewer does quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: How about NoMachine then? I know it can pass hardware remotely. Maybe that may help.

Comment: Wow, that looks really promising, this is the first I've heard of it. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: If it works, I'll repost my comment as an answer so you can accept it.